# Arch USB will no longer boot - '/dev/disk/by-label/' device did not show up after 30 seconds

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub2, live-usb, uefi

While I was configuring this first (well, third to be honest) Arch install attempt, I neglected to edit the default boot entries created after installing GRUB2 beta with `pacman`. So of course when I rebooted to test my settings, not only did I find that my system won't properly boot, but I no longer have any boot entries to load a USB recovery image. Bummer.

I managed to `set root` manually and boot into the USB, but before I can successfully get to the `root` prompt I hit this notorious error:

`ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label' device did not show up after 30 seconds...`

and

`sh: can't access tty: job control turned off`

I've looked at several solutions and still no dice. If I've missed something please let me know:

- verified device detection with `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`
- `ln -s[f] /dev/sda /dev/disk/by-label`
- `archisodevice=ARCH_201611`
- `udevadm trigger`
- `mount /dev/sda[1] /bootmnt/archiso`
- renaming the USB drive to `ARCH_201611`*
- `mv /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201611 /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201611`*

**(see below)*

I've reformatted the USB drive as `ext4` and `GPT` and used `dd` to load the ISO as per the installation guide. I'm installing Arch on a Thinkpad t420s with Intel i5 2520M and UEFI enabled.

Perhaps the issue is that I haven't labelled the drive properly? I used Disk Utility on my Mac (2015 Retina MBp) to rename the USB drive to `ARCH_201611`, wipe it clean, and then reload the `iso` with `dd`. When I attempt the above rename method, there is already a label for `ARCH_201611` in the `/dev/` directory. However, the error message always prints `/dev/disk/by-label` - not `/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201611`. It's possible that the device labels are changed when the iso loads, but being as macOS cannot mount the device after the `iso` is loaded, I don't know of any way to apply a new label to the device. Any recommendations?

Maybe [if I could edit my boot entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_GNU.2FLinux_2) - how would I do that in the `rootfs` fallback shell?

In the meantime, maybe I'll try [Netboot](https://releng.archlinux.org/pxeboot/)...

PS: I am aware that this question belongs on the Arch forums, but since I don't have a working installation at this point, I'm unable to get the output needed to answer the `date -u +%V$(uname)...` question required to create an account.

Comment: Update: I fixed my boot entries in the BIOS by reloading default settings with F9